# Assembly is loaded differently via AssemblyResolve?

Tags: c#, assemblyresolve, microsoft.extensions.logging

I have an app which dynamically loads a DLL from a different folder.

This DLL needs `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll`, and if I load it before I load my DLL, it works fine:

```
void f()
{
   Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\\DllFolder\\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll");
   Assembly mydll = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\\DllFolder\\MyDLL.dll");
   CallMethodFromMyDll(mydll); // works great :-)
}
```

Alas, if I use `AssemblyResolve` to load `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll` from the same folder,
I get a `missingExceptionMethod`:

```
void f()
{
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyAssemblyResolveFunction;
   Assembly mydll = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\\DllFolder\\MyDLL.dll");
   CallMethodFromMyDll(mydll); // MissingExceptionMethod.... :-(
}

Assembly MyAssemblyResolveFunction(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
   var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\\DllFolder\\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll";

   if (assembly != null)
   {
        // the code gets here!
        return assembly;
   }

   return null;
}
```

The exception message:

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel)'.

I already checked that the assembly loaded by `AssemblyResolve` is from the same location. Why does it behave differently?

Comment: Maybe `MyAssemblyResolveFunction` is (also) being called for some assembly other than the one your code expects - check `args`.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ConsoleLoggerExtensions` is not in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll` but in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll`. You need to make sure this dll is also resolved correctly.